# EC2 java sdk -> launching an instance with a public ip

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to launch an instance into a subnet with a default setting of not assigning public IPs.

With the aws CLI, this is done by adding `--associate-public-ip-address`:

```
aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-xxx --count 1 --instance-type m4.large --key-name "xxx" --subnet-id subnet-xxx --security-group-ids sg-xxx --associate-public-ip-address
```

How to do the same thing when launching an instance using the Java SDK?

```
RunInstancesRequest runInstancesRequest = new RunInstancesRequest();

runInstancesRequest.withImageId(kAmiId)
                   .withInstanceType(kInstanceType)
                   .withMinCount(1)
                   .withMaxCount(1)
                   .withKeyName(kKeyName)
                   .withSecurityGroupIds(kSecurityGroups)
                   .withMonitoring(false)
                   .withSubnetId(kSubnet);
```

Got it working like this:

```
InstanceNetworkInterfaceSpecification networkSpec = new InstanceNetworkInterfaceSpecification();
networkSpec.setDeviceIndex(0);
networkSpec.setSubnetId(kSubnet);
networkSpec.setGroups(Arrays.asList(kSecurityGroups));
networkSpec.setAssociatePublicIpAddress(true);

runInstancesRequest.withImageId(kAmiId)
                   .withInstanceType(kInstanceType)
                   .withMinCount(1)
                   .withMaxCount(1)
                   .withKeyName(kKeyName)
                   .withMonitoring(false)
                   .withNetworkInterfaces(networkSpec)
                   .withAdditionalInfo("--associate-public-ip-address");

RunInstancesResult result = mClient.runInstances(runInstancesRequest);
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have to set it by providing a `InstanceNetworkInterfaceSpecification`. Something like this:

```
List<InstanceNetworkInterfaceSpecification> interfaces = new ArrayList<InstanceNetworkInterfaceSpecification>();
interfaces.add(new InstanceNetworkInterfaceSpecification().withAssociatePublicIpAddress(true));

runInstancesRequest.withNetworkInterfaces(interfaces);
```

Comment: Thanks! Got it working after looking  at the .NET documentation. I'll add the working sample in the question.